# Select row if next a value in next row is null

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I need to know how to select a row if the next row has a null value for specific column.
For example:

---

```
Ind      | Opt50    | Stat
44       | 1        | NR
45       | 1        | CL    
46       | NULL     | NULL   
47       | 1        | IE    
48       | NULL     | NULL    
49       | NULL     | NULL   
50       | 1        | NR  
51       | 1        | IE
52       | 1        | CL
53       | 1        | IE    
54       | NULL     | NULL
```

---

If Status is 'IE' and Option50 is NULL for the next record, then I need to return that next record. For the table above I need the query to find ind 47 and 53 and to return ind 48 and 54.

---

```
Ind      | Opt50    | Stat  
48       | NULL     | NULL
54       | NULL     | NULL
```

---

I am using SQL Server 2008. 
Any ideas?

Comment: Is your column `ind` always sequential as per your example? If so, why not do a self join on ind=ind-1 and then test for the criteria?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that the column `Ind` is a correlative, then:

```
SELECT  B.*
FROM dbo.YourTable A
INNER JOIN dbo.YourTable B
    ON A.Ind = B.Ind - 1
WHERE A.Stat = 'IE' 
AND B.Opt50 IS NULL
```

[**Here is a**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a9fa9/1) sqlfiddle with a demo of this.

And the results are:

```
╔═════╦════════╦════════╗
║ Ind ║ Opt50  ║  Stat  ║
╠═════╬════════╬════════╣
║  48 ║ (null) ║ (null) ║
║  54 ║ (null) ║ (null) ║
╚═════╩════════╩════════╝
```

In the case that `Ind` has gaps in it, then you can do:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  *,
            RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Ind)
    FROM dbo.YourTable
)

SELECT  B.*
FROM CTE A
INNER JOIN CTE B
    ON A.RN = B.RN - 1
WHERE A.Stat = 'IE' 
AND B.Opt50 IS NULL
```

[**Here is a**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a9fa9/2) sqlfiddle with this version.

Comment: @Conduit Yeah, I guess so ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Here you go! You can also use the PARTITION clause in the LEAD and LAG functions if you need. If this helps or you find it interesting, please up vote me so I can get lots of points so I can be cool!
Peace
Katherine

```
declare @table table (
[ind]     [int]
, [opt50] [int]
, [stat]  [nvarchar](25));
insert into @table
        ([ind],[opt50],[stat])
values      (1,1,N'IE'),
        (2,2,N'NotIE'),
        (3,null,N'IE'),
        (4,4,N'NotIE');
with [builder]
 as (select [ind]
            , [opt50]
            , [stat]
            , lag ([opt50]
                   , 1
                   , 0)
                over (
                  order by [ind] asc) as [next_opt50]
     from   @table)
select [ind]
   , [opt50]
   , [stat]
   , [next_opt50]
   , case
         when [opt50] is null
             then
           [next_opt50]
         else
           [opt50]
     end as [what_i_really_want]
from   [builder];
```