# How to access the previous record in a select statement in SQL Server 2008 R2?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

A community consultation, it brings me to my query this data:

```
ID_KAR   ALMACEN               FECHA                    CODIGO_PROD  MONTO
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
16275   AVIOS E INSUMOS 2011-01-01 00:00:00.000 0       ANS0001UNI  18100.0000  
39823   AVIOS E INSUMOS 2011-06-06 00:00:00.000 2       ANS0001UNI  18100.0000  
8718    AVIOS E INSUMOS 2011-01-01 00:00:00.000 0       AV-AC-766   9015.0000   
23243   AVIOS E INSUMOS 2011-01-06 00:00:00.000 2       AV-AC-766   477.0000    
23247   AVIOS E INSUMOS 2011-01-06 00:00:00.000 2       AV-AC-766   40.0000 
23255   AVIOS E INSUMOS 2011-01-06 00:00:00.000 2       AV-AC-766   35.0000 
23251   AVIOS E INSUMOS 2011-01-06 00:00:00.000 2       AV-AC-766   118.0000
```

Turns out I need to add a column to the query more, but that data I obtain an estimate of the query.
I need to access the previous record for calculating the new amount.

I need to access the data from the previous record, if I positioned itself in register 2, I need to access the 1 to show the new amount in register 2.

Comment: Your question was not clear enough to explain what you are expecting. You can do Group by or SUM() or computed columns or subquery which may be useful for your situation. Add some more info to your question.

Comment: Are you looking for a reference to the "previous row" (even though there's no order of rows in a table...) or the running total of all "previous rows"?

Comment: Sorry for not explaining it correctly, what I need is when the SELECT is listing from the second to compare the product code with ASN001 ASN001 ASN001 the previous record, and make the same comparison with all records.

Comment: If you are running sql server 2012 or later you can use lead/lag as I've defined here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25693078/select-row-if-next-a-value-in-next-row-is-null/25693900#25693900

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best bet is to use a CTE and row_number or Rank
Then doing a n-1 in the join.
So something like:

```
WITH 
ANSICTE
AS
(
SELECT  RANK() OVER (Partition BY Codigo_Prod ORDER BY fecha ASC ) as Ranks
,Codigo_Prod  
FROM Table
)
SELECT ANSICTE.Codigo_Prod, ANSICTE.Ranks, ANSICTE2.Fecha, ...
FROM ANSICTE
LEFT OUTER JOIN ANSICTE AS ANSICTE2
    ON ANSICTE.CODIGO_Prod = ANSICTE2.Codigo_Prod
    AND ANSICTE.Ranks = ANSICTE2.Ranks-1
```

Comment: SQL Server 2012 supports lead and lag functions, those would be better in the future, but for now...